# Run Simulators docked in VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code, android-emulator, ios-simulator

Is it possible to run iOS or Android simulator docked inside VSCode (or is there a feature request or extension to do so)? ideally as one of the tabs in the panel, where the Terminal is.

UPDATE:
the best workaround solution I could come up with is dragging the ios simulator on a native macos space, as seen in picture. this is not doable on windows or linux afaik

[image: ios simulator docked with vscode in a macos space]